# Paperclip add image from URL in has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, has-many

I've this models:
Prodcuts -> Products_Images.

I can add multiple images from a form uploading the image that it's my computer. I want to add images from URLs instead of locally images.

Paperclip has added this feature:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Attachment-downloaded-from-a-URL
but I don't know how to apply it in a has_many association.

I've tried adding a method in ProductImages model and call it for each URL after product is created. I don't know if I must use this method directly in Product model.

Where should I try to put the method of the wiki of Paperclip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great gist (that I did not write).  It should get you there: https://gist.github.com/jgv/1502777

```
require 'open-uri'

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :image # etc...

  before_validation :download_remote_image, :if => :image_url_provided?

  validates_presence_of :image_remote_url, :if => :image_url_provided?, :message => 'is invalid or inaccessible'

  private

  def image_url_provided?
    !self.image_url.blank?
  end

  def download_remote_image
    io = open(URI.parse(image_url))
    self.original_filename = io.base_uri.path.split('/').last
    self.image = io
    self.image_remote_url = image_url
  rescue # catch url errors with validations instead of exceptions (Errno::ENOENT, OpenURI::HTTPError, etc...)
  end

end
```

All credit to the author.

In the future, it's usually best to post the code with your attempt to solve the problem.